# Notepad ++ Utf-8 Conversion for multiple files in folder

Tags: notepad++

I want to convert the files in folder with .da2 extension to UTF 8 encoding.I tried python script and macro but did not work in my case. Please help. I have around 500 files in the folder

TIA

Tried python script from old thread and also macro but format didn’t change